# How to get temporary credentials with AWS Roles Anywhere programmatically w/ Node.js?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-sts, aws-roles

I have a non-AWS workload that needs to access the AWS API. Using IAM Roles Anywhere to generate temporary credentials as opposed to using long-term credentials (e.g. access keys) is recommended by AWS for security purposes.

1. I have set up a Certificate Authority using AWS Certificate Manager
2. I have created a Trust anchor
3. I have created a Profile

I am now ready to authenticate via the certificate trusted by my trust anchor and obtain temporary credentials from a role, but I have no idea how to do that programmatically and I don't see any useful doc on this subject.

There are some [command-line helper tools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rolesanywhere/latest/userguide/credential-helper.html) that AWS provides, but I need to write code, not use a command line app.

I probably need to use the [Security Token Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/sts/), but I don't see any method that takes in a certificate and returns credentials. `AssumeRoleCommand` and `GetSessionTokenCommand` seem like good candidates, but again, I'm not sure how to use them in the context of the Roles Everywhere feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't see any method that takes in a certificate and returns credentials

This is because `CreateSession` i.e. the X.509 wrapper around `AssumeRole` practically has no SDK support as per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rolesanywhere/latest/userguide/authentication-create-session.html#create-session-and-assume-role):

> `CreateSession` is **not included in any SDK or client** as there is not yet native SDK or client support for CreateSession's signing process.

You'll need to manually implement the [signing process](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rolesanywhere/latest/userguide/authentication-sign-process.html) in JS/TS, using the source code for [`rolesanywhere-credential-helper`](https://github.com/aws/rolesanywhere-credential-helper) as support. Do note that [`RolesAnywhereClient`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/rolesanywhere/) is a control-plane package & doesn't actually sign requests.

---

The lack of SDK support is rather disappointing more than a year after release, so I've reached out to the AWS team to ask about potential SDK support & if this is on the roadmap anytime soon. I'll update my answer if/when I hear back from them.